# python searching Russian substrings in excel

Tags: python, string, unicode

I want to read excel file and extract some information concerning some people.

Here is what i am doing

```
import xlrd
dir = './schfiles';
files = os.listdir(dir);
f = files[0];
book = xlrd.open_workbook(dir+"/"+files[0]);
sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)
t = sh.cell_value(rowx=xlr2i(35),colx=xlc2i('F'))
t.find(u"Усманов")
```

the string written in var t is u'\u0434\u043e\u0446. \u0423\u0441\u043c\u0430\u043d\u043e\u0432 \u0411.\u0428.' which looks like "доц. Усманов Б.Ш."

u"Усманов" is represented as u'\xd3\xf1\xec\xe0\xed\xee\xe2'

i tried encoding both strings into 'utf8', decoding them, using external libs, but nothing helped.

Does anyone know how is it possible to find a particular substring here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` as the first line of your script to tell the intepreter which encoding are you using.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import xlrd

dir = './schfiles'
files = os.listdir(dir)
f = files[0]

workbook_path = os.path.join(dir, files[0])
book = xlrd.open_workbook(workbook_path)

sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)
t = sh.cell_value(rowx=xlr2i(35),colx=xlc2i('F'))
t.find(u"Усманов")
```

Comment: So, how do i know what encoding should i use?

Comment: Use `utf-8` for non-ascii characters, Python 2.x uses `ASCII` as default encoding.

Comment: @PheuVerg, To be clear, `#coding:utf8` declares the encoding of the *source file*.  `t.find(u'Усманов')` should be a Unicode string and make sure to save the source file in the declared encoding.  Then Python will know how to correctly build the Unicode string.  You can use any encoding for your source file that allows you to correctly represent your language, but the declared encoding and the actual saved encoding must agree.

Comment: Make absolutely sure you declare any literals with Unicode text as `unicode` literals: use `u"Усманов"` on Python 2. It looks like the OP is about Python 2 so you may need to fix that in your answer.